# Get XML or JSON Representation from POGO

Tags: xml, json, groovy

Is there way in groovy by which i can get either XML or JSON representation of that POGO, similar to what i can have in JAVA by annotating POJO?

Example:

Below POGO needs to converted to either JSON or XML at runtime

```
class User {
   String name
   String address
}
```

I tried `JSONBuilder`, but could not find anything which can convert this to XML as well.

Comment: so you don't need either, but you need both?

Comment: also your java library with the annotations also works with a POGO (most likely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @cfrick comments, it is quite likely that your java library and annotations will work also for POGOs (are you using JAXB?).

Anyway, for JSON output, you can use `JSONBuilder`

```
class User {
   String name
   String address
}

def user = new User(name: 'John', address: 'Bake St.')
println new JsonBuilder(user).toPrettyString()
---
{
    "address": "Bake St.",
    "name": "John"
}
```

For a quick solution regarding XML, you can use [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/):

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='com.thoughtworks.xstream', module='xstream', version='1.4.7')
)

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.*

[...]    

def xstream = new XStream()
println xstream.toXML(user)
---
<User>
  <name>John</name>
  <address>Bake St.</address>
</User>
```

If you want a kind of a "common" processing for JSON and XML, you can use [groovy's builder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Builders) mechanism, passing a closure with nested method calls and nested closures to the builder:

```
def userC = { 
    name('Kevin')
    address('Train St.')
}

def json = new JsonBuilder()
json userC
println json.toPrettyString()

def writer = new StringWriter()
def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
xml.'User' userC
println writer.toString()
---
{
    "name": "Kevin",
    "address": "Train St."
}
<User>
  <name>Kevin</name>
  <address>Train St.</address>
</User>
```

Or with the [`StaxBuilder`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/xml/StaxBuilder.html), a builder that works with Stax processors. Using [jettison](http://jettison.codehaus.org/), you can somehow unify JSON and XML processing:

```
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='org.codehaus.jettison', module='jettison', version='1.3.7')
)

import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException

import groovy.json.*
import groovy.xml.*

import org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.*

def userC = { 
    name('Kevin')
    address('Train St.')
}

[...]

def factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance()
writer = new StringWriter()
def stax = new StaxBuilder(factory.createXMLStreamWriter(writer))
stax.'User' userC
println writer.toString()

def conv = new MappedNamespaceConvention()
writer = new StringWriter()
def mappedWriter = new MappedXMLStreamWriter(conv, writer)
staxJson = new StaxBuilder(mappedWriter)
staxJson.'User' userC
println writer.toString()
---
<?xml version="1.0" ?><User><name>Kevin</name><address>Train St.</address></User>
{"User":{"name":"Kevin","address":"Train St."}}
```